# linqpad + linq2sql custom model

Tags: linq-to-sql, linqpad

I'm trying to get LinqPad use my dbml model so I could analyze a query from my source code. I've set the DataContext to "Custom LINQ to SQL DataContext", and all the necessary settings, unfortunately even with the simplest query I get an error :

```
QUERY: from m in Linia select m
ERROR: Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'MyNameSpace.Linia'.  'Select' not found.
```

Does anybody know how to get this to work? Thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it! By default, LINQPad pluralizes table properties in the DataContext. I should have used Linias instead of Linia.